# How to stream video form device to ingestion server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, socket.io, mediarecorder, amazon-ivs

I'm building a live streaming app (one-to-many) and am using AWS IVS as my ingestion server.

Now, I get the video feed from `mediaRecorder` api transmits the video using socket.io as a buffer. Now the challenge is to parse the real-time buffers to AWS IVS or any other ingestion server.

I figured that the only way to stream the video is by using `ffmpeg` and that's where am completely stuck.

Here is my code

```
// ffmpeg config
const { spawn, exec } = require("child_process");

let ffstr = `-re -stream_loop -1 -i ${input} -r 30 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -preset veryfast -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" -minrate 3000 -maxrate 3000 -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmps://${INGEST_ENDPOINT}:443/app/${STREAM_KEY}`;

let ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", ffstr.split(" "));

// Socket.io
socket.on("binarystream", async (mBuffer) => {
      // TODO: Get the buffer
      // TODO: Ingest/convert to mp4
      // TODO: Stream to IVS

      // TODO: FFMpeg is your best bet
      // console.log(mBuffer);

      ffmpeg.stdin.write(mBuffer);
      
  });
```

PS: Even if you don't have the direct answers I'm available for discussion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the following two samples from AWS Samples github repo that shows how you can send a webrtc stream to IVS endpoint from a browser.

**Frontend**
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-simple-streaming-webapp

**Backend configuration with ffmpeg**
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-simple-streaming-webapp/blob/main/backend/transwrap_local.js